# Is there an evalScripts: false (from mootools) equivalent in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I read the specs on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
and found that depending on the dataType, scripts are automatically evaluated for every response. Is it then possible to force jQuery not to evaluate the script parts of the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `dataType` to `text`.

Comment: will it still be HTML format? i mean the response definitely will be HTML (those which needs DOM manipulation before i append it to the actual page)

Comment: @lock then you should use the data type `xml`